# How to change part of a whole layout by keeping other part constant

Tags: android

My layout having two parts.

I want to change the upper part by keeping the bottom part constant..

I dont want to use fregments here.

I am trying this code.
But it changes from one layout to another

```
lin.removeAllViews();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second, null);
        lin.addView(v2);
```

Basically i have five layouts that i want to change on the top part of main layout .. I want clicking on first layout second layout appears and than clicking on second layout third layout appears and so on till five screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a vertical LinearLayout with two children of fixed size, where the child you want to change is a ViewSwitcher. Then set and remove the ViewSwitcher's children as you wish.